# Undefined method 'to_h' on Ruby array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, ruby-2.0

As per [Ruby Array documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h), there is a method `to_h` which can be used to convert arrays to hash as long as each element of the array is another array of two elements.  Example below from the same documentation

```
p [[:foo, :bar], [1, 2]].to_h
```

However, when I run the above code, I get this error:

```
irb(main):001:0> p [[:foo, :bar], [1, 2]].to_h
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_h' for [[:foo, :bar], [1, 2]]:Array
        from (irb):1
        from E:/RubyInstall/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):002:0>
```

My Ruby version is

```
C:\>ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x64-mingw32]
```

I wanted to use this technique to answer another question on Stackoverflow, but I am stuck now as a documented feature of Ruby is not working for me.

Comment: As a note you can still use the compatible `Hash::[]` syntax like `Hash[[[:foo, :bar], [1, 2]]]` to produce the same result in Ruby < 2.1

Comment: @engineersmnky That sounds awesome!

Comment: You should upgrade to at least v2.1. 2.0 had some problems (e.g. `Refinements`).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sure will do

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `to_h` method is only available in Ruby version 2.1 or higher.

Check the release notes here

http://pivotallabs.com/ruby-2-1-0-changes-of-note/

Comment: Thanks.  Will upgrade my Ruby. :-)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's not supported for lower version than Ruby 2.1, If you are looking for alternative. Try this

```
keys = [:foo, :bar]
vals = [1, 2]
Hash[*keys.zip(vals).flatten]
 => {:foo=>1, :bar=>2}
```

Comment: Worth noting that in the Ruby 2.1.0 `to_h` documentation, `[[:foo, :bar], [1, 2]].to_h` should result in `{:foo => :bar, 1 => 2}`  https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-to_h

Answer (score 7):

The following code will monkey patch Array and provide a `to_h` method using the code give in @engineersmnky's comment, if `to_h` isn't already defined - that is, in pre-2.1 ruby environments.

```
unless [].respond_to? :to_h
  class Array
    def to_h
      Hash[self]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Ruby 2.0 doesn't support to_h method. its available in 2.1 and higher