# Summarize an array of hashes with a crosstab (also called a 'pivot table')

Tags: ruby, aggregate

I have an array of hashes like this:

```
my_array_of_hashes = [
  { :customer=>"Matthew",
    :fruit=>"Apples",
    :quantity=>2,
    :order_month => "January"
  },
  { :customer => "Philip",
    :fruit => "Oranges",
    :quantity => 3,
    :order_month => "July"
  },
  { :customer => "Matthew",
    :fruit => "Oranges",
    :quantity => 1,
    :order_month => "March"
  },
  { :customer => "Charles",
    :fruit => "Pears",
    :quantity => 3,
    :order_month => "January"
  },
  { :customer => "Philip",
    :fruit => "Apples",
    :quantity => 2,
    :order_month => "April"
  },
  { :customer => "Philip",
    :fruit => "Oranges",
    :quantity => 1,
    :order_month => "July"
  }
]
```

which I would like to summarize in a `row-column` format. Using my sample data this would mean summing the `:quantity` values, with one row per unique customer, one column per unique fruit.

```
-----------------------------------
Customer | Apples | Oranges | Pears
Charles  |        |         |   3            
Matthew  |   2    |    1    |
Philip   |   2    |    4    |
-----------------------------------
```

This feels like something solvable with Ruby `enumerables` but I can't see how.

Comment: Did you try something?

Comment: It is worth looking into [terminal-table gem](https://github.com/tj/terminal-table), which certainly could help build the table with an output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Create arrays needed to construct the table**

I will construct three arrays that contain row labels (`customers`), column labels (`fruit`) and the values in the table (`values`).

```
arr_of_hash = [
  {:customer=>"Matthew", :fruit=>"Apples",  :quantity=>2, :order_month=>"January"},
  {:customer=>"Philip",  :fruit=>"Oranges", :quantity=>3, :order_month=>"July"   },
  {:customer=>"Matthew", :fruit=>"Oranges", :quantity=>1, :order_month=>"March"  },
  {:customer=>"Charles", :fruit=>"Pears",   :quantity=>3, :order_month=>"January"},
  {:customer=>"Philip",  :fruit=>"Apples",  :quantity=>2, :order_month=>"April"  }, 
  {:customer=>"Philip",  :fruit=>"Oranges", :quantity=>1, :order_month=>"July"   }
]

customers = arr_of_hash.flat_map { |g| g[:customer] }.uniq.sort
  #=> ["Charles", "Matthew", "Philip"]
fruit = arr_of_hash.flat_map { |g| g[:fruit] }.uniq.sort
  #=> ["Apples", "Oranges", "Pears"]
h = customers.each_with_object({}) { |cust,h| h[cust] = fruit.product([0]).to_h }
  #=> {"Charles"=>{"Apples"=>0, "Oranges"=>0, "Pears"=>0},
  #    "Matthew"=>{"Apples"=>0, "Oranges"=>0, "Pears"=>0},
  #    "Philip" =>{"Apples"=>0, "Oranges"=>0, "Pears"=>0}} 
arr_of_hash.each do |g|
  customer = g[:customer]
  h[customer][g[:fruit]] += g[:quantity]
end
values = h.map { |_,v| v.values }
  #=> [[0, 0, 3],
  #    [2, 1, 0],
  #    [2, 4, 0]]
```

Note that immediately before `values = h.map { |_,v| v.values }`:

```
  h #=> {"Charles"=>{"Apples"=>0, "Oranges"=>0, "Pears"=>3},
  #      "Matthew"=>{"Apples"=>2, "Oranges"=>1, "Pears"=>0},
  #      "Philip" =>{"Apples"=>2, "Oranges"=>4, "Pears"=>0}}
```

**Print the table**

```
def print_table(row_labels_title, row_labels, col_labels, values, gap_size=3)
  col_width = [values.flatten.max.size, col_labels.max_by(&:size).size].max + gap_size
  row_labels_width = [row_labels_title.size, row_labels.max_by(&:size).size].max +
    gap_size
  horiz_line = '-'*(row_labels_width + col_labels.size * col_width + col_labels.size)
  puts horiz_line
  print row_labels_title.ljust(row_labels_width)
  col_labels.each do |s|
    print "|#{s.center(col_width)}"
  end
  puts
  row_labels.each do |row_label|
    print row_label.ljust(row_labels_width)
    vals = values.shift
    col_labels.each do |col_label|
      print "|#{vals.shift.to_s.center(col_width)}"
    end
    puts
  end
  puts horiz_line
end

print_table("Customers", customers, fruit, values, 2)
--------------------------------------------
Customers  |  Apples  | Oranges  |  Pears   
Charles    |    0     |    0     |    3     
Matthew    |    2     |    1     |    0     
Philip     |    2     |    4     |    0     
--------------------------------------------
```

Comment: .to_h on line 14, "h = customers.each_with..." is throwing an undefined method error for me.

Comment: Tom, I cannot reproduce that error. It works fine for me. I'm using Ruby 2.4.0, but I don't think it would be a version issue.

Comment: [.to_h is available since 2.1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31684031/6150184)

Comment: @DiodonHystrix, yes, of course. Thanks. For earlier versions of Ruby the line ending `.to_h` can be replaced with `h = Hash[customers.each_with_object({}) { |cust,h| h[cust] = fruit.product([0])] }`.

Comment: @Cary, thank you -- it _was_ a version issue after all and suddenly revealed that I didn't have rvm on my machine. Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a hash with a default value of a hash with a default value of 0 :) :

```
fruits = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(0) }
fruits[:some_name]
# {}
p fruits[:some_name][:some_fruit]
# 0
```

That way, you don't need any logic inside your loop, you just iterate over the hashes and add the quantities :

```
my_array_of_hashes = [ {:customer=>"Matthew", :fruit=>"Apples", :quantity=>2, :order_month => "January"}, {:customer => "Philip", :fruit => "Oranges", :quantity => 3, :order_month => "July"}, {:customer => "Matthew", :fruit => "Oranges", :quantity => 1, :order_month => "March"}, {:customer => "Charles", :fruit => "Pears", :quantity => 3, :order_month => "January"}, {:customer => "Philip", :fruit => "Apples", :quantity => 2, :order_month => "April"}, {:customer => "Philip", :fruit => "Oranges", :quantity => 1, :order_month => "July"} ]

fruits = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(0) }

my_array_of_hashes.each do |hash|
  fruits[hash[:customer]][hash[:fruit]] += hash[:quantity]
end

p fruits
# {
#  "Matthew"=>{"Apples"=>2, "Oranges"=>1},
#  "Philip"=>{"Oranges"=>4, "Apples"=>2},
#  "Charles"=>{"Pears"=>3}
#  }
```